# Can you help me to get rid of this? Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type search to be controlled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this warning and I don't know how to get rid of this.
I got a main component Measurements that contains a search icon. When I click on the icon, the icon expands to a search bar.
This search bar is a component importend to Measurements component.
When I type in the search bar this warning with controlled/uncontrolled component.

- "react": "^16.12.0",
- "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.1",
- "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
- "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.42",

```
    Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type search to be controlled. 
Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). 
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. 
More info: h t tps:/ /fb .me /react-controlled-components
        in input (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
        in div (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
        in ForwardRef(InputBase) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)))
        in WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)) (created by ForwardRef(Input))
        in ForwardRef(Input) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Input)))
        in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Input)) (created by ForwardRef(TextField))
        in div (created by ForwardRef(FormControl))
        in ForwardRef(FormControl) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(FormControl)))
        in WithStyles(ForwardRef(FormControl)) (created by ForwardRef(TextField))
        in ForwardRef(TextField) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField)))
        in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField)) (at Search.js:63)
        in div (at Search.js:52)
        in Search (at Measurements.js:862)
        in div (at Measurements.js:857)
        in div (at Measurements.js:833)
        in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
        in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
        in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (at Measurements.js:832)
        in div (at Measurements.js:831)
        in div (at Measurements.js:817)
        in div (at Measurements.js:811)
        in Measurements (created by Context.Consumer)
        in Route (at Content.js:74)
        in Switch (at Content.js:68)
        in main (at Content.js:64)
        in Content (at Main.js:469)
        in div (at Main.js:189)
        in ThemeProvider (at Main.js:187)
        in Main (at App.js:53)
        in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
        in BrowserRouter (at App.js:52)
        in App (at src/index.js:19)
        in Provider (at src/index.js:18)
```

And my component looks like this:

```
import { InputAdornment, TextField } from '@material-ui/core'
import { SearchOutlined } from '@material-ui/icons'
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'
import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

import styles from './Search.module.scss'

const handleNewSearchValue = debounce(props => {
  const { dispatch, changePage, setSearchValue, name, value } = props
  dispatch(changePage(1))
  if (value) {
    setSearchValue({ [name]: value })
  } else {
    setSearchValue({})
  }
}, 1000)

export default function Search(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const {
    openSearch,
    handleOpenSearch,
    setSearchValue,
    preSearchValue,
    setPreSearchValue,
    changePage,
  } = props

  const handleSearch = e => {
    const { value, name } = e.target

    const handlePreSearchAndSearch = () => {
      if (value) {
        setPreSearchValue({ [name]: value })
      } else {
        setPreSearchValue({})
      }
      handleNewSearchValue({
        dispatch,
        changePage,
        setSearchValue,
        name,
        value,
      })
    }

    return handlePreSearchAndSearch()
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={` ${styles.searchBar} ${
        openSearch && styles.expandedSearchBar
      }`}>
      {!openSearch ? (
        preSearchValue && preSearchValue.criteria ? (
          <p className={styles.searchValue}>{preSearchValue.criteria}</p>
        ) : (
          <SearchOutlined className={styles.searchIcon} />
        )
      ) : (
        <TextField
          className={styles.searchInput}
          fullWidth
          autoComplete='off'
          type='search'
          autoFocus
          name='criteria'
          value={preSearchValue.criteria}
          InputProps={{
            disableUnderline: true,
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment
                onClick={() => handleOpenSearch(false)}
                position='start'
                className={styles.inputAdornment}>
                <Search fontSize='small' />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
          }}
          onChange={handleSearch}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Search component is imported to another component:

```
export default function Measurements() {

//search state
  const [openSearch, setOpenSearch] = useState(false)
  const [preSearchValue, setPreSearchValue] = useState({})
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState({})

  const handleOpenSearch = open => {
    if (open && !openSearch) {
      setOpenSearch(open)      
    }
    if (!open && openSearch) {
      setOpenSearch(open)
    }
  }

....

  useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(fetchMeasurements(searchValue))
  },[searchValue])

return (
  <>
    <div className={`${styles.searchButton} ${openSearch && styles.expandedSearchBar}`}
        onClick={() => handleOpenSearch(true)}>
          <SearchBar
            openSearch={openSearch}
            handleOpenSearch={handleOpenSearch}                      
            searchValue={searchValue}
            setSearchValue={setSearchValue}
            preSearchValue={preSearchValue}
            setPreSearchValue={setPreSearchValue}
            changePage={changePage}
      />
     </div>
....
  <>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

This happens when an input's value changes from `undefined` to a defined value.

Measurements

```
const [preSearchValue, setPreSearchValue] = useState({});
```

Search

```
value={preSearchValue.criteria}
```

Even though `preSearchValue` is defined it is an empty object (`{}`) but `preSearchValue.criteria` will be undefined initially, so when setting the value in the text input it doesn't have a defined value and react assumes it is an uncontrolled input.

## Solution

Provide some initial state

```
const [preSearchValue, setPreSearchValue] = useState({
  criteria: '',
});
```

Or provide a fallback value at the input

```
value={preSearchValue.criteria || ''}
```